# swift string separation but include the

Tags: swift, string

I need to separate a string to a array of substring but need to include `",.?!"` as the substring in Swift.

```
var sentence = "What is your name?" into
var words = ["What", "is", "your", "name", "?"]
```

I know I can use this to separate the white space, but I need the `".,?!"` to be separated into a word in the words array.  How can I do that?

```
var words = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")
```

I only get `["What", "is", "your", "name?"]`

I need to separate the ? at the end word, and make words array like this:

```
var words = ["What", "is", "your", "name", "?"]
```

Comment: What if the sentence contains "  ??!    ", what is the desired output? Should each punctuation symbol be represented by an element in `words`? How should emoji be treated? How about apostrophes "I'm here", "a woman's hat", " two childrens' hats "

Comment: @LeoDabus I feel that you're on the right path, some little tweaking here and there would make it work. "¿Cómo te llamas?" is another edge case. I am still waiting for for the OP's feedback

Comment: @ielyamani yes we need OP feedback otherwise we will be just guessing

Comment: Sorry about the late reply.  @LeoDabus. Your answer is very nice. and I like the swift native one.   Thank you

Comment: @Emmy Actually replaceOccurrences also belongs to Foundation Framework https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences

Comment: @Emmy I have added a native approach as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enumerate your substrings in range using `.byWords` options, append the substring to your words array, get the substring range `upperBound` and the enclosed range `upperBound`, remove the white spaces on the resulting substring and append it to the words array:

---

```
import Foundation

let sentence = "What is your name?"
var words: [String] = []
sentence.enumerateSubstrings(in: sentence.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { substring, range, enclosedRange, _ in
    words.append(substring!)
    let start = range.upperBound
    let end = enclosedRange.upperBound
    words += sentence[start..<end]
        .split{$0.isWhitespace}
        .map(String.init)
}

print(words) // "["What", "is", "your", "name", "?"]\n"
```

---

You can also use a regular expression to replace the punctuation by the same punctuation preceded by a space before splitting your words by whitespaces:

```
let sentence = "What is your name?"
let words = sentence
    .replacingOccurrences(of: "[.,;:?!]",
                          with: " $0",
                          options: .regularExpression)
    .split{$0.isWhitespace}

print(words)  // "["What", "is", "your", "name", "?"]\n"
```

---

Swift native approach:

```
var sentence = "What is your name?"
for index in sentence
    .indices
    .filter({ sentence[$0].isPunctuation })
    .reversed() {
    sentence.insert(" ", at: index)
}
let words = sentence.split { $0.isWhitespace }
words.forEach { print($0) }
```

---

This will print:

> What
>
> is
>
> your
>
> name
>
> ?

Comment: Additionally, you could take care of *latino* punctuation marks https://pastebin.com/Qg3dCVgT

Answer (score 1):

This function will split on whitespace and also include each punctuation character as a separate string.  Apostrophes are treated as part of a word, so "can't" and "it's" are kept together as a single string.  This function will also handle double spaces and tabs.

```
func splitSentence(sentence: String) -> [String] {
  var result : [String] = []
  var word = ""
  let si = sentence.startIndex
  for i in 0..<sentence.count {
    let c = sentence[sentence.index(si, offsetBy: i)]
    if c.isWhitespace {
      if word.count > 0 {
        result.append(word)
        word = ""
      }
    } else if (c.isLetter || (String(c) == "'")) {
      word = word + String(c)
    } else {
      if word.count > 0 {
        result.append(word)
        word = ""
      }
      result.append(String(c))
    }
  }
  if word.count > 0 {
    result.append(word)
  }
  return result
}
```

Here is some testing code:

```
func test(_ sentence: String, _ answer: [String]) {
  print("--------------------------------")
  print("sentence=" + sentence)
  let result : [String] = splitSentence(sentence: sentence)
  for s in result {
    print("s={" + s + "}")
  }
  if answer.count != result.count {
    print("#### Answer count mismatch")
  }
  for i in 0..<answer.count {
    if answer[i] != result[i] {
      print("### Mismatch: {" + answer[i] + "} != {" + result[i] + "}")
    }
  }
}

func runTests() {
  test("", [])
  test(" ", [])
  test("  ", [])
  test(" a", ["a"])
  test("a ", ["a"])
  test("  a", ["a"])
  test(" a ", ["a"])
  test("a  ", ["a"])
  test("aa", ["aa"])
  test("a a", ["a", "a"])
  test("?", ["?"])
  test("a?", ["a", "?"])
  test("???", ["?", "?", "?"])
  test("What is your name?", [ "What", "is", "your", "name", "?" ])
  test("What  is your name? ", [ "What", "is", "your", "name", "?" ])
  test("La niña es linda.", [ "La", "niña", "es", "linda", "."])
  test("ñññ ñ ññ ñ", [ "ñññ", "ñ", "ññ", "ñ" ])
  test("It's the 'best'.", [ "It's", "the", "'best'", "." ])
  test("¿Cómo te llamas?", [ "¿", "Cómo", "te",  "llamas", "?" ])
  test("你好吗？", [ "你好吗", "？" ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
XCTAssertEqual(
  "¿What is your name? My name is , and I am a cat!"
    .split(separator: " ")
    .flatMap { $0.split(includingSeparators: \.isPunctuation) }
    .map(Array.init)
    .map { String($0) },
  [ "¿", "What", "is", "your", "name", "?",
    "My", "name", "is", "", ",", "and", "I", "am", "a", "cat", "!"
  ]
)
```

```swift
public enum Spliteration<Element> {
  case separator(Element)
  case subSequence([Element])
}

public extension Array {
  init(_ spliteration: Spliteration<Element>) {
    switch spliteration {
    case .separator(let separator):
      self = [separator]
    case .subSequence(let array):
      self = array
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// The first element of the sequence.
  /// - Note: `nil` if the sequence is empty.
  var first: Element? {
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    return iterator.next()
  }

  func split(includingSeparators getIsSeparator: @escaping (Element) -> Bool)
  -> AnySequence< Spliteration<Element> > {
    var separatorFromPrefixIteration: Element?

    func process(next: Element?) -> Void {
      separatorFromPrefixIteration =
        next.map(getIsSeparator) == true
        ? next
        : nil
    }

    process(next: first)
    let prefixIterator = AnyIterator(
      dropFirst(
        separatorFromPrefixIteration == nil
        ? 0
        : 1
      ),
      processNext: process
    )

    return .init {
      if let separator = separatorFromPrefixIteration {
        separatorFromPrefixIteration = nil
        return .separator(separator)
      }

      return Optional(
        prefixIterator.prefix { !getIsSeparator($0) },
        nilWhen: \.isEmpty
      ).map(Spliteration.subSequence)
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension AnyIterator {
  /// Use when `AnyIterator` is required / `UnfoldSequence` can't be used.
  init<State>(
    state: State,
    _ getNext: @escaping (inout State) -> Element?
  ) {
    var state = state
    self.init { getNext(&state) }
  }

  /// Process iterations with a closure.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - processNext: Executes with every iteration.
  init<Sequence: Swift.Sequence>(
    _ sequence: Sequence,
    processNext: @escaping (Element?) -> Void
  ) where Sequence.Element == Element {
    self.init( state: sequence.makeIterator() ) { iterator -> Element? in
      let next = iterator.next()
      processNext(next)
      return next
    }
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension AnySequence {
  /// Use when `AnySequence` is required / `AnyIterator` can't be used.
  /// - Parameter getNext: Executed as the `next` method of this sequence's iterator.
  init(_ getNext: @escaping () -> Element?) {
    self.init( Iterator(getNext) )
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Wraps a value in an optional, based on a condition.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - wrapped: A non-optional value.
  ///   - getIsNil: The condition that will result in `nil`.
  init(
    _ wrapped: Wrapped,
    nilWhen getIsNil: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows {
    self = try getIsNil(wrapped) ? nil : wrapped
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not answering using swift, but I believe the algorithm can be emulated with any language.
Done the implementation using Java. The code uses standard Java libraries and not external ones.

```
private void setSpecialCharsAsLastArrayItem() {

    String name = "?what is your name?";


    String regexCompilation = "[$&+,:;=?@#|]";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(regexCompilation);

    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(name);
    StringBuilder regexStr = new StringBuilder();


    while (matcher.find()) {
        regexStr.append(matcher.group());
    }


    String stringOfSpecialChars = regexStr.toString();
    String stringWithoutSpecialChars = name.replaceAll(regexCompilation, "");

    String finalString = stringWithoutSpecialChars + " "+stringOfSpecialChars;
    String[] splitString = finalString.split(" ");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString));

}
```

will print `[what, is, your, name, ??]`

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution (Swift 5):

```
let sentence = "What is your name?".replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: " ?")
let words = sentence.split(separator: " ")
print(words)
```

Output:

```
["What", "is", "your", "name", "?"]
```

Comment: Sorry that someone downvoted you.  I did not.  you answered my question. But I think Leo's answer is more general for most cases.   Thanks for your effort and that is a smart answer. :)